# Saved format output in columns [grep, sed, awk or ?]

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed, expect

I have created a Expect Script file that telnet to multiple +200 switches.

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
#Slurp up the input file
set fp [open "ip.txt" r]
# To avoid empty lines, 'nonewline' flag is used
set file_data [read -nonewline $fp]
close $fp
set prompt ">"
log_file -noappend switch_port_status.txt
foreach ip [split $file_data "\n"] {
puts "Switch $ip Interface Status"
spawn telnet $ip
expect "Username:"
send "MyUsername\r"
expect "assword:"
send "MyPassword\r"
expect $prompt
# To avoid sending 'Enter' key on huge configurations
send "show ip int br\r"
expect {
-ex "--More--" { send -- " "; exp_continue }
"*>" { send "exit\r" }
}
#expect $prompt
set timeout 1; # Reverting to default timeout
# Sending 'exit' at global level prompt will close the connection
expect eof
```

For Expect Script "log_file -noappend switch_port_status.txt", I have saved a output file as below:

```
Trying 192.168.0.1...
Connected to 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1).
Escape character is '^]'.

Authorized access only
This system is the property of Company Name
Disconnect IMMEDIATELY if you are not an authorized users!


User Access Verification

Username: MyUsername
Password:

Switch-hostname1>show ip int br
Interface              IP-Address  OK? Method          Status                 Protocol
Vlan1                  unassigned  YES  NVRAM          administratively down  down
Vlan308                192.168.0.1 YES  NVRAM          up                     up
Vlan603                unassigned  YES  NVRAM          administratively down  down
GigabitEthernet0/1     unassigned  YES  unset          up                     up
GigabitEthernet0/2     unassigned  YES  unset          down                   down
LongReachEthernet0/1   unassigned  YES   unset         administratively down  down
LongReachEthernet0/2   unassigned  YES   unset         administratively down  down
LongReachEthernet0/3   unassigned  YES   unset         administratively down  down
LongReachEthernet0/4   unassigned  YES   unset         administratively down  down
LongReachEthernet0/5   unassigned  YES   unset         administratively down  down
LongReachEthernet0/6   unassigned  YES   unset         up                     up
LongReachEthernet0/7   unassigned  YES   unset         up                     up
LongReachEthernet0/8   unassigned  YES   unset         administratively down  down
LongReachEthernet0/9   unassigned  YES   unset         administratively down  down
LongReachEthernet0/10 unassigned  YES   unset         up                     up
LongReachEthernet0/11 unassigned  YES   unset         administratively down  down
LongReachEthernet0/12 unassigned  YES   unset         administratively down  down
LongReachEthernet0/13 unassigned  YES   unset         administratively down  down
LongReachEthernet0/14 unassigned  YES   unset         administratively down  down
LongReachEthernet0/15 unassigned  YES   unset         administratively down  down
LongReachEthernet0/16 unassigned  YES   unset         up                     up
LongReachEthernet0/17 unassigned  YES   unset         administratively down  down
LongReachEthernet0/18 unassigned  YES   unset         administratively down  down
LongReachEthernet0/19 unassigned  YES   unset         administratively down  down
LongReachEthernet0/20 unassigned  YES   unset         up                     up
LongReachEthernet0/21 unassigned  YES   unset         administratively down  down
LongReachEthernet0/22 unassigned  YES   unset         administratively down  down
LongReachEthernet0/23 unassigned  YES   unset         administratively down  down
LongReachEthernet0/24 unassigned  YES   unset         administratively down  down
Switch-hostname1>exit
Connection closed by foreign host.
Trying 192.168.0.2...
Connected to 192.168.0.2 (192.168.0.2).
Escape character is '^]'.

Authorized access only
This system is the property of Company Name
Disconnect IMMEDIATELY if you are not an authorized users!


User Access Verification

Username: MyUsername
Password:

Switch-hostname2>show ip int br
Interface             IP-Address  OK? Method   Status                Protocol
Vlan1                 unassigned  YES NVRAM    administratively down down
Vlan308               192.168.0.2 YES NVRAM    up                    up
Vlan603               unassigned  YES NVRAM    administratively down down
GigabitEthernet0/1    unassigned  YES unset    up                    up
GigabitEthernet0/2    unassigned  YES unset    down                  down
LongReachEthernet0/1  unassigned  YES unset    administratively down down
LongReachEthernet0/2  unassigned  YES unset    administratively down down
LongReachEthernet0/3  unassigned  YES unset    administratively down down
LongReachEthernet0/4  unassigned  YES unset    down                  down
LongReachEthernet0/5  unassigned  YES unset    administratively down down
LongReachEthernet0/6  unassigned  YES unset    administratively down down
LongReachEthernet0/7  unassigned  YES unset    administratively down down
LongReachEthernet0/8  unassigned  YES unset    administratively down down
LongReachEthernet0/9  unassigned  YES unset    administratively down down
LongReachEthernet0/10 unassigned YES unset     administratively down down
LongReachEthernet0/11 unassigned YES unset     administratively down down
LongReachEthernet0/12 unassigned YES unset     administratively down down
LongReachEthernet0/13 unassigned YES unset     administratively down down
LongReachEthernet0/14 unassigned YES unset     administratively down down
LongReachEthernet0/15 unassigned YES unset     administratively down down
LongReachEthernet0/16 unassigned YES unset     administratively down down
LongReachEthernet0/17 unassigned YES unset     administratively down down
LongReachEthernet0/18 unassigned YES unset     up up
LongReachEthernet0/19 unassigned YES unset     administratively down down
LongReachEthernet0/20 unassigned YES unset     administratively down down
LongReachEthernet0/21 unassigned YES unset     administratively down down
LongReachEthernet0/22 unassigned YES unset     up up
LongReachEthernet0/23 unassigned YES unset     administratively down down
LongReachEthernet0/24 unassigned YES unset     administratively down down
Switch-hostname2>Trying 192.168.0.3...
Connected to 192.168.0.3 (192.168.0.3).
Escape character is '^]'.

Authorized access only
This system is the property of Company Name
Disconnect IMMEDIATELY if you are not an authorized users!


User Access Verification

Username: MyUsername
Password:

Switch-hostname3#show ip int br
Interface            IP-Address  OK? Method     Status Protocol
Vlan1                192.168.0.3 YES NVRAM      up     up
FastEthernet0/1      unassigned  YES unset      up     up
FastEthernet0/2      unassigned  YES unset      up     up
FastEthernet0/3      unassigned  YES unset      up     up
FastEthernet0/4      unassigned  YES unset      up     up
FastEthernet0/5      unassigned  YES unset      up     up
FastEthernet0/6      unassigned  YES unset      up     up
FastEthernet0/7      unassigned  YES unset      up     up
FastEthernet0/8      unassigned  YES unset      down   down
FastEthernet0/9      unassigned  YES unset      down   down
FastEthernet0/10    unassigned  YES unset       down   down
FastEthernet0/11    unassigned  YES unset       down   down
FastEthernet0/12    unassigned  YES unset       down   down
FastEthernet0/13    unassigned  YES unset       down   down
FastEthernet0/14    unassigned  YES unset       down   down
FastEthernet0/15    unassigned  YES unset       down   down
FastEthernet0/16    unassigned  YES unset       down   down
FastEthernet0/17    unassigned  YES unset       down   down
FastEthernet0/18    unassigned  YES unset       down   down
FastEthernet0/19    unassigned  YES unset       down   down
FastEthernet0/20    unassigned  YES unset       down   down
FastEthernet0/21    unassigned  YES unset       down   down
FastEthernet0/22    unassigned  YES unset       up     up
FastEthernet0/23    unassigned  YES unset       down   down
FastEthernet0/24    unassigned  YES unset       down   down
GigabitEthernet0/1  unassigned  YES unset       up     up
GigabitEthernet0/2  unassigned  YES unset       down   down
Switch-hostname4>exit
Connection closed by foreign host.

Trying 192.168.0.4...
Connected to 192.168.0.4 (192.168.0.4).
Escape character is '^]'.

Authorized access only
This system is the property of Company Name
Disconnect IMMEDIATELY if you are not an authorized users!


User Access Verification

Username: MyUsername
Password:

Switch-hostname4#show ip int br
```

............so on and so forth.

Can this be done with awk/sed/grep utility in Linux??

Desired output format:

```
192.168.0.1
Switch-hostname1
Vlan1,administratively down
Vlan308,up 
Vlan603,administratively down
GigabitEthernet0/1,up 
GigabitEthernet0/2 ,down
LongReachEthernet0/1,administratively down
LongReachEthernet0/2,administratively down
LongReachEthernet0/3,administratively down
LongReachEthernet0/4,administratively down
LongReachEthernet0/5,administratively down
LongReachEthernet0/6,up
LongReachEthernet0/7,up
LongReachEthernet0/8,administratively down
LongReachEthernet0/9,administratively down
LongReachEthernet0/10,up
LongReachEthernet0/11,administratively down
LongReachEthernet0/12,administratively down
LongReachEthernet0/13,administratively down
LongReachEthernet0/14,administratively down
LongReachEthernet0/15,administratively down
LongReachEthernet0/16,up
LongReachEthernet0/17,administratively down
LongReachEthernet0/18,administratively down
LongReachEthernet0/19,administratively down
LongReachEthernet0/20,up
LongReachEthernet0/21,administratively down
LongReachEthernet0/22,administratively down
LongReachEthernet0/23,administratively down
LongReachEthernet0/24,administratively down

192.168.0.2
Switch-hostname2
Vlan1,administratively
Vlan308,up
Vlan603,administratively
GigabitEthernet0/1,up
GigabitEthernet0/2,down
LongReachEthernet0/1,administratively
LongReachEthernet0/2,administratively
LongReachEthernet0/3,administratively
LongReachEthernet0/4,down
LongReachEthernet0/5,administratively
LongReachEthernet0/6,administratively
LongReachEthernet0/7,administratively
LongReachEthernet0/8,administratively
LongReachEthernet0/9,administratively
LongReachEthernet0/10,administratively
LongReachEthernet0/11,administratively
LongReachEthernet0/12,administratively
LongReachEthernet0/13,administratively
LongReachEthernet0/14,administratively
LongReachEthernet0/15,administratively
LongReachEthernet0/16,administratively
LongReachEthernet0/17,administratively
LongReachEthernet0/18,up
LongReachEthernet0/19,administratively
LongReachEthernet0/20,administratively
LongReachEthernet0/21,administratively
LongReachEthernet0/22,up
LongReachEthernet0/23,administratively
LongReachEthernet0/24,administratively

192.168.0.3
Switch-hostname3
Vlan1,up
FastEthernet0/1,up
FastEthernet0/2,up
FastEthernet0/3,up
FastEthernet0/4,up
FastEthernet0/5,up
FastEthernet0/6,up
FastEthernet0/7,up
FastEthernet0/8,down
FastEthernet0/9,down
FastEthernet0/10,down
FastEthernet0/11,down
FastEthernet0/12,down
FastEthernet0/13,down
FastEthernet0/14,down
FastEthernet0/15,down
FastEthernet0/16,down
FastEthernet0/17,down
FastEthernet0/18,down
FastEthernet0/19,down
FastEthernet0/20,down
FastEthernet0/21,down
FastEthernet0/22,up
FastEthernet0/23,down
FastEthernet0/24,down
GigabitEthernet0/1,up
GigabitEthernet0/2,down

192.168.0.4
Switch-hostname4
```

............so on and so forth.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: very exhaustive but a bit huge (in information) for a *simple* reformat

Comment: Your output is a full one or filtered, example no exit from 192.168.0.2 but for other well, .... In other word, what are your criteria to take lines and reformat it ?

Comment: The output is a full one, it automatically outputs like this. We should omit the following words if we suppose there is an exit:

『Trying IP Address...
Connected to IP Address (IP Address).
Escape character is '^]'.

Authorized access only
This system is the property of Company Name
Disconnect IMMEDIATELY if you are not an authorized users!

User Access Verification

Username: MyUsername
Password:』

『>show ip int br』

『>exit
Connection closed by foreign host.』

Comment: Only IP, hostname, interface & status required to get the ouput file condition as mentioned in my post.

May I edit expect script in order to convert output file to the desired format output above? Or do I need to open another perl file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Dmitry Egorov Thank you very much!
Desired output format as in my post. This is my post format problem when i return to the switch with the script copy i posted. The problem fixed by not using "$".

Your previous code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -nl

print "\n$1" if (/Connected to (\S+)/);
if ($line_num = (/^(\S+?)(?:>|#)show ip int br/ ... /^.*?(?:>|#)/)) {
    if ($line_num == 1) {
        print $1;
    } elsif ($line_num > 2 && /^(\S+)\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(.*)\s+\S+$/) {
        print "$1;$2";
    }
}
```

My current code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -nl

print "\n$1" if (/Connected to (\S+)/);
if ($line_num = (/^(\S+?)(?:>|#)show ip int br/ ... /^.*?(?:>|#)/)) {
    if ($line_num == 1) {
        print $1;
    } elsif ($line_num > 2 && /^(\S+)\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(.*)\s+\S+/)  {
        print "$1;$2";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As for perl implementation, I'd suggest this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -nl

print "\n$1" if (/Connected to (\S+)/);
if ($line_num = (/^(\S+?)(?:>|#)show ip int br/ ... /^.*?(?:>|#)/)) {
    if ($line_num == 1) {
        print $1;
    } elsif ($line_num > 2 && /^(\S+)\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(.*)\s+\S+$/)  {
        print "$1;$2";
    } elsif ($line_num > 2 && /^\s*$/)  {   # retian empty lines after 
                                            # 'show ip int br' if there are any
        print;
    }
}
```

Usage: `squeeze.pl your_swicth_status_script_output.txt` where `squeeze.pl` is the name of the script above.

Comment: I've changed the script to take into account various prompt character and potentially missing "exit" commands

Comment: The script you provide is work, yet there is another problem. When i return to the switch with the script copy i posted, i can get the expected result by using the perl you provided, as shown. But the lines are not separated after "show ip interface brief" if i used the same perl to run the output file in the previous switch. I have attempted to edit yet failed, please kindly suggest how i can make the amendments. Thank you so much.

Comment: [Format as my post]:
(http://i109.photobucket.com/albums/n73/CyberLuk/post%20format.jpg~original)
[Script work]:
(http://i109.photobucket.com/albums/n73/CyberLuk/post%20result%20done.jpg~original)
[Original format into the switch]:
(http://i109.photobucket.com/albums/n73/CyberLuk/switch%20file_2.jpg~original)
[Only display IP&hostname]:
(http://i109.photobucket.com/albums/n73/CyberLuk/switch%20result%20failed_2.jpg~original)

[Download link of original output file]:
(https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0tUlNEULMxqZkt2WXZwcnVWcWc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi @DannyLuk! Do I get it right that you need to preserve empty lines in the interface table if there are any? If so, please use the updated script version from the answer. Otherwise would you please specify your requirements in more details?

Comment: Thank you very much!
Desired output format as in my post. This is my post format problem when i return to the switch with the script copy i posted. The problem fixed by not using "$".